Setting Up Ubuntu Headless Server for Homelab – Need Some Guidance

Hello everyone,
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and currently setting up a homelab. I've installed Ubuntu Server (headless) on my main machine, and while I can log in through the terminal, I'm feeling a bit lost on what to do next. Here's what I've done so far:

Installation and Basics:

Successfully installed Ubuntu Server.
Comfortable navigating the terminal.


Goals:

Deploy multiple VMs.
Test different distros.
Eventually build my own distro.
Manage devices on the network.
Monitor logs and network activity.


Current State:

Ubuntu Server is up and running.
I have LXD and snaps installed.
ams.amc Installed.
Ubuntu Pro enabled.
I installed very little amountd of packages.


Questions:

How do I deploy VMs using LXD? What's the process?
How can I connect other clients to these VMs?
Should I stick with the headless setup or switch to a GUI interface for ease of use?



I appreciate any guidance or advice you can provide. Looking forward to contributing back to the Ubuntu community!
Thank you!


Hi again. Much better structure, however your question still include multiple parts, some of which could be considered opinion based. BUT, as for LXD, there is actually some good official guidance on the Ubuntu website, and there are also several other guides online. Start here, and you'll get closer to your first 2 questions. I'm afraid the 3rd question is purely opinion based, and thus off-scope for this site.

Thanks! I'm learning! Really I've had a ball with the whole experience, I get to break things and then fix them, I figured it would be opinion, I guess a better question would be what are the pros and cons of a headless vs gui environment

"How do I deploy VMs using LXD? What's the process?" See the tutorial at https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/running-virtual-machines-with-lxd-4-0/7519

"How can I connect other clients to these VMs?" See the orientation to LXD networking at https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/explanation/networks/ and https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/networks/

@user535733 yea the reference that Artur posted was exactly what I was looking for and I've been reading a lot and probably skimmed or just didn't see the documentation.
